# passing props from redux returns initial value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-props

Can someone help me with this issue.
I am using Redux and Typescript for a little project.
I pass the redux global state as props using mapStatetoProps in my container component **CartContainer.tsx**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchOffers } from "../../../api/fetchOffers";
import Cart from "../presentation/Cart";

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  items: state.shoppingCartReducer.items,
  discountedOffer: state.shoppingCartReducer.discountedOffer,
  total_cart: state.shoppingCartReducer.total_cart
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  getOffers: (items: any[]) => fetchOffers(items),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

this is my presentational component **Cart.tsx**, in which I console.log the props to print out the values of the properties I need, 
I import the props like so :

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, Fragment, useCallback } from "react";
import { ShoppingCart } from '../../organismes/ShoppingCart'
import { CommercialOffer } from "../../../models/Offer";

export interface ICartProps {
  items: any[]; 
  total_cart: number, 
  discountedOffer: CommercialOffer, 
  getOffers: (items: any[]) => void;
}
const Cart = (props: ICartProps) => {
  const { items, total_cart, getOffers } = props;
  const loadOffers = useCallback(() => getOffers(items), [items, getOffers]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(props)
    loadOffers()
  }, [loadOffers, items, total_cart]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ShoppingCart {...props}/>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default Cart;
```

I use the react tools to inspect what props are available.
The 2 props I need, **discountedOffer** and **total_cart** are here with the value:

[image]

However, values are never available as shown in the screenshot below. Same for the front, I can never refer to the props.

[image]

Comment: These logs are coming from `CartFooter.tsx` not `Cart.tsx`?!

Open log in `Cart.tsx:15`

Comment: try to:
 - log outside the useLayoutEffect
 - log console.log(tems, total_cart, getOffers) - since you've emptied the props object with the spread operator

Comment: I am printing from both Cart.tsx and CartFooter.tsx. this is the same results. not the expected results for the properties mentioned

Comment: Your `mapDispatchToProps()` does not actually bind `getOffers()` handler to ***dispatching*** anything. You're fetching your data asynchronously, are you sure the data arrives before component is actually re-rendered? In that regard, is there any rationale behind using `useLayoutEffect()` [rather than](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) `useEffect()`?